# Puppet on Windows create service with generated service name

Tags: puppet, puppet-enterprise

I'm writing a module to install a package and configure it afterwards, the package installation is working fine, however, to add some custom configuration I need to restart the service and that isn't working, So the code below install the package, and supposed to, , finds the Service ID (it's different everytime it get's installed) and stop the service, however, I get this error, when I tried Puppet agent reports "Error: Evaluation Error: Error while evaluating a Function Call, Could not find any files from C:\Atlassian\JIRA.install4j\installation.id",

```
package { "${jira::package_name} ${jira::version}":
ensure          => "${jira::version}",
allow_virtual   => false, 
provider        => 'windows',
source          => "${jira::extractdir}\\${file}",
install_options => ['-q', '-varfile', $response_varfile]
} 

$jira_win_serviceid = file(" C:\Atlassian\JIRA\.install4j\installation.id")

service { "${jira_win_serviceid}":
  ensure => 'stopped',
  enable => true,
}
```

I'm also trying via exec, but no lucky yet

Comment: Functions execute on the master and therefore that file will not be found since you are attempting to load it off a client node, which is not possible with an intrinsic function. You will need to go in a different direction here.

Comment: for some reason i find it hard to believe that the jira service name changes on each install.. but i'm naive to jira installsm especially on windows... have you tried installing manually then looking at the serv'ice name?